# How to input pictures with subfloat in IEEE latex

Tags: subfloats

I write latex with IEEEtrans with TexLive version 2022.

I would like to input two pictures where Picture A is at the top and Picture B is at the bottom as follows.

[image: expectation]

Here is the latex code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \subfloat[Picture A]{
         \includegraphics[width=2 in]{Picture_A.png}
         \label{fig: first}}
        \subfloat[Picture B]{
         \includegraphics[width=2 in]{Picture_B.png}
         \label{fig: second}}
    \caption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig: Picture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, the result is Picture A and Picture B parallel as follows.

[image: result]

What I need to include in the coding? Thank you.

Comment: Adding ` \\ ` after the `\subfloat{...}` will do. Moreover, you may like to use `width=\linewidth` for each `\includegraphics` in the `\subfloat`.

Comment: or insert empty line between each subfigure ...

Answer (score 1):

As already noted in comments, you have two possibilities  how to achieved desired position of sub images:

- insert `\\` after end of subfloat environment, or
- inset empty lines between them (as is done in MWE below)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[ht]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \centering
        \subfloat[Picture A]{
         \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Picture_A.png}
         \label{fig: first}}
         
        \subfloat[Picture B]{
         \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Picture_B.png}
         \label{fig: second}}
    \caption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig: Picture}
\end{figure}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Zarko, how can we edit the code if I want : Fig. 1: Picture 1 (a) Picture A. (b) Picture B? Under each picture only (a) and (b) with no description.

Comment: @NicholasTI, I have a problem to understand your comment. If you like to have just `(a)` and `(b)` under sub images, than simply drop-out text in square brackets: `\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{...}}`.